Bounty option or timer missing?
I wanted to reward an answer with a modest bounty. Other questions have this option below the comment option, even if there is an accepted answer. But for my last question, it just disappeared!

My question may not be eligible for bounty, but in such cases I ordinarily see the bounty timer, „eligible for bounty in 19 hours“ which I don’t see now (maybe I am just looking in the wrong place?).
Edit: now, as two days have passed the option has appeared. It is still unclear, why the timer had disappeared before.

This is what I normally see, when the question is not yet eligible for bounty:


See https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/bounty:

How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

It hasn't been two days since you've asked the question.

Ok. But normally, when I cannot see the bounty option, I get the timer! „Question eligible for bounty in 24 hours „ or something such.

Pls see edited question on how I expected the timer to look!

I think the link disappears because you've accepted the answer.  This may indeed be a bug, since bounties can be awarded on questions with accepted answers.
Here's one of my questions to check...
Before...



After...




That's interesting, but is that really a bug? Bounties are for people looking for better answers - if you've accepted an answer, it is "sufficient to qualify as the best answer", so you wouldn't start a bounty on it. People who didn't ask the question may have a different opinion to you, so I can see why they would start a bounty.

Whether or not it’s a bug is a matter of opinion, I guess.
